# COUNTIFS using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use COUNTIFS :

My first Criteria is based on color preference (blue vs. red).
Second criteria is based on operating system preference (Apple vs. Android).

The problem I'm having is that for my 3rd criteria, I need 3 parameters but all three of those parameters are in the same column.
I'm trying to figure out how many counts are BLUE > Apple > Metal or Glass or Plastic.
Based on this, my formula should return a number 3.

```
blue    Apple   Metal
red     Apple   Glass
blue    Apple   Plastic
red     Apple   Metal
blue    Android Glass
red     Apple   Carbon Fiber
blue    Apple   Metal
red     Apple   Glass
blue    Android Carbon Fiber
red     Apple   Carbon Fiber
```

Here is the current formula :

```
=COUNTIFS(A3:A12,"blue",B3:B12,OR(COUNTIF(C3:C12,"Metal"),COUNTIF(C3:C12,"Glass"),COUNTIF(C3:C13,"Plastic")))
```

Comment: A filter may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach using SUMPRODUCT.

`=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A12="blue")*(B3:B12="apple")*ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"metal","glass","plastic"},C3:C12,1)))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you over complicated it. You nested a bunch of `countif` in a formula that already has a `countifs`... rather than selecting everything but carbon fiber, this formula counts if it is a Blue Apple that isn't Carbon Fiber...

```
=COUNTIFS(A3:A12,"blue",B3:B12,"Apple",C3:C12,"<>Carbon Fiber")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula within the `COUNTIFS`:

```
={SUM(COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$12, "Blue", $B$3:$B$12, "Apple", $C$3:$C$12, {"Metal","Plastic","Glass"}))}
```

Note that the {} at the start and end represent the array formula and are applied by using Ctrl + Shift + Enter.